# Is this possible to use jquery dependant script (lazy load) before jquery.js script tag (footer)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm getting html from ajax callback. Inside this content I have script tag for loading a code which uses jQuery, but I have always `jQuery` is undefined error.

All scripts are attached before `</body>`

Is this any option to make this work, besides moving jQuery to the head?

Comment: I dont think its possible other than adding it before the code that requires it

Answer (score 1):

As @Milind said, in conventional way using JQuery it is not possible. But you can check the below url.

http://www.yterium.net/jQl-an-asynchronous-jQuery-Loader

They have developed a way to do what you want. They do something like below. But go through the link for more informations.

```
jQl.loadjQ('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js');
jQl.loadjQdep('js/myplugin.jquery.js');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(function(){
var tId = setInterval(function(){if(document.readyState == "complete") onComplete()},11);
function onComplete(){
    clearInterval(tId);    
    alert("document loaded!");    
    };
})()
```

Replace the 'alert("document loaded!"); ' code with your scripts. This checks to see if the document is fully loaded first (gives it time for jQuery to load) and then executes the alert.

Your issue sounds like your getting dynamic content which has the script tags inside. Might be easier using jQuery's on(); function on the outer page to process the page? ( http://api.jquery.com/on/ ).

Giving an example would make it a lot easier to identify the full problem.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't necessarily need to move it to the head, but as long as you move it to before your ajax call then it should be fine.